# Cannot install gurobi for python on macbook

Tags: python, anaconda, gurobi

I use anaconda to install gurobi.

1. I install the gurobi software
2. I install anaconda
3. I already have an academic license for gurobi.

Then I create an environment for python 3.6.3 with anaconda.
After installing gurobi, I cannot find the package gurobipy.

I don't know why this happen....

---

Specific:

```
Last login: Wed Nov 29 01:39:25 on ttys000
appledeMacBook-Pro-5:~ apple$ source activate python36
(python36) appledeMacBook-Pro-5:~ apple$ conda install gurobi
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/apple/anaconda3/envs/python36:
#
gurobi                    7.5.2                    py36_0    gurobi
(python36) appledeMacBook-Pro-5:~ apple$
```

---

When I use pycharm

```
from gurobipy import *

try:
    # Create a new model
    m = Model("mip1")
    # Create variables
    x = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
    y = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y")
    z = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="z")
    # Set objective
    m.setObjective(x + y + 2 * z, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
    # Add constraint: x + 2 y + 3 z <= 4
    m.addConstr(x + 2 * y + 3 * z <= 4, "c0")
    # Add constraint: x + y >= 1
    m.addConstr(x + y >= 1, "c1")
    m.optimize()
    for v in m.getVars():
        print(v.varName, v.x)
        print('Obj:', m.objVal)
except GurobiError:
    print('Error reported')
```

The result is

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

---

I find that there must be something wrong with anaconda. I copy the package from anaconda to other environment and it works. There must be some package conflict with gurobi. And that's why exit code 139. I also intall mosek in anaconda. This solver can work under anaconda's environment.

```
from cvxpy import *
import mosek


# Create two scalar optimization variables.
x = Variable()
y = Variable()

# Create two constraints.
constraints = [x + y == 1,
               x - y >= 1]

# Form objective.
obj = Minimize(square(x - y))

# Form and solve problem.
prob = Problem(obj, constraints)
prob.solve(solver=MOSEK)

# The optimal dual variable (Lagrange multiplier) for
# a constraint is stored in constraint.dual_value.
print("optimal (x + y == 1) dual variable", constraints[0].dual_value)
print("optimal (x - y >= 1) dual variable", constraints[1].dual_value)
print("x - y value:", (x - y).value)
print(installed_solvers())
```

The result is

```
/Users/apple/anaconda3/envs/python36/bin/python "/Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/optimal-transport/作业/homework 5/practice.py"
optimal (x + y == 1) dual variable -0.0
optimal (x - y >= 1) dual variable 2.00000600065164
x - y value: 1.0000000011

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

---

The packages in anaconda

```
CVXcanon    0.1.1   0.1.1
Mosek   8.1.33  7.0.123
ca-certificates 2017.08.26  
certifi 2017.11.5   2017.11.5
cvxcanon    0.1.1   
cvxpy   0.4.9   0.4.11
dill    0.2.7.1 0.2.7.1
ecos    2.0.4   2.0.5
ecos    2.0.5   2.0.5
fastcache   1.0.2   1.0.2
gurobi  7.5.2   
intel-openmp    2018.0.0    2018.0.0
libcxx  4.0.1   
libcxxabi   4.0.1   
libedit 3.1 
libffi  3.2.1   
libgcc  4.8.5   
libgfortran 3.0.1   
mkl 2018.0.1    2018.0.0
multiprocess    0.70.4  0.70.5
ncurses 6.0 
numpy   1.13.3  1.13.3
openssl 1.0.2m  
pip 9.0.1   9.0.1
python  3.6.3   
readline    7.0 6.2.4.1
scipy   1.0.0   1.0.0rc2
scs 1.2.6   2.0.1
setuptools  36.5.0.post20170921 38.2.3
setuptools  36.5.0  38.2.3
six 1.11.0  1.11.0
sqlite  3.20.1  
tk  8.6.7   
toolz   0.8.2   0.8.2
wheel   0.30.0  0.30.0a0
xz  5.2.3   
zlib    1.2.11
```

Comment: gurobipy, the python-package, needs to be installed too (and is not part of a general gurobi-software install). What did you get from the [docs](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/quickstart_mac/the_gurobi_python_interfac.html)? Furthermore: when asking for help for things like that, a more detailed description of what you did is important! (e.g. changing environment/path-variables: although probably irrelevant here; yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use Gurobi with Anaconda Python is to use Conda install from [the instructions](http://www.gurobi.com/downloads/get-anaconda).

- Activate the Anaconda environment you want use. If your root environment is 3.6.3, then you don't need to do anything.
- Install Gurobi.
- Open Gurobi in terminal and copy your key with

  ```
  grbgetkey your_gurobi_key
  ```
- Add the gurobi channel to the list of repositories conda uses

  ```
  conda config --add channels http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi
  ```
- Install the Gurobi Anaconda Python libraries

  ```
  conda install gurobi
  ```
- check your installation in iPython:

  ```
  m = grb.Model()
  vars = [m.addVar(name="x." + str(i)) for i in range(n)]
  m.update()
  constrs = [m.addConstr(vars[i] <= i) for i in range(n)]
  m.update()
  retval = m.optimize()
  ```

or use this [simple script](https://gist.github.com/abremod/0c4146f33ddca9370186d341bf0ae195) to check if the libraries and license are installed:

```
python abrecheck.py
```

Comment: I did this, but i still cannot use the gurobipy.

Comment: open gurobi from the launchpad and will open a terminal window, than do the grbgetkey with your key and should work, without license won't work

Comment: you should get this: Gurobi license key client (version 7.5.2)
Copyright (c) 2017, Gurobi Optimization, Inc.

-------------------------------
Contacting Gurobi key server...
-------------------------------

Key for license ID xxxxxx was successfully retrieved.
License expires at the end of the day on 2018-11-28.

---------------------
Saving license key...
---------------------

In which directory would you like to store the Gurobi license key file?
[hit Enter to store it in /Users/sb]:

Comment: i have activated my academic license.

Comment: than the problem is with your anaconda, just upgrade the conda and create new environment and see if solves.

Comment: @WillCai Did you try running the test script from a command line?  What happens?

Comment: I find that there must be something wrong with anaconda. I copy the package from anaconda to other environment and it works. There must be some package conflict with gurobi.  And that's why exit code 139. 

I also intall mosek in anaconda. This solver can work under anaconda's environment.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to some reported issues running Gurobi 7.5+ and Anaconda with python 3.x on macOS/linux (not sure of exact versions).

e.g. this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gurobi/6lw13VjvXsE

Not sure of exactly what the configuration combination is that breaks it, but I've got it working with python 2.7 after experiencing this segfault problem.

```
conda info...

      conda version : 4.5.0
conda-build version : 3.7.2
     python version : 2.7.14.final.0
           platform : osx-64
         user-agent : conda/4.5.0 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.14 Darwin/17.5.0 OSX/10.13.4

conda list...
gurobi                    7.5.2                    py27_0    gurobi
```

I've read that a downgraded version of anaconda but still keeping python 3.x may work too, but couldn't repeat that solution.